# action create not working Yii2 frontend

Tags: php, yii2, action

i want to execute action create in my view frontend, the code of actionCreate in site controller is correct , but it redirect me to index.php with this url "http://localhost/advanced/frontend/web/index.php?Subsidize%5Bname%5D..........."
knowing that i want to redirect to view.php after creating a new item in table "subsidize"

action create in siteController.php

```
public function actionView($id) {
    $model = Subsidize::findOne($id);
    if ($model === null) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException;
    }

    return $this->render('view', [
                'model' => $model,
    ]);
}

public function actionCreate() {
    $model = new Subsidize();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {

         return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->subsidize_id]);


    } else {

        return $this->render('create', [
                    'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

code of  submitButton in view "create.php"

```
        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'إرسال ' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
```

also , function behaviors in  siteController

```
 public function behaviors() {
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'only' => ['create'],
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'actions' => ['login', 'error'],
                    'allow' => true,
                ],
                [
                    'actions' => ['create', 'view'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                ],
                [
                    //see captcha and error added here, this fixes the issue
                    'actions' => ['support', 'test', 'delete', 'update', 'create', 'view'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['?', '@'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'verbs' => [
            'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
            'actions' => [
                'index' => ['get'],
                'view' => ['get'],
                'create' => ['get', 'post'],
                'update' => ['get', 'put', 'post'],
                'delete' => ['post', 'delete'],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

code of my view : create.php

```
<?php use yii\helpers\Html; use yii\widgets\ActiveForm; $model = new app\models\Subsidize; ?> <section class="support">
<div class="container">       
    <form class="dialog-form row">
        <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin() ?>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">             


                <?php echo $form->field($model, 'name', [
       'inputOptions' => ['autofocus' => 'autofocus', 'class' => 'form-control transparent']
 ])->textInput()->input('name', ['placeholder' => "الإسم الكريم"])->label(false); ?>

            </div><!--End Form-group-->
        </div><!-- col -->
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                 <?php echo $form->field($model, 'montant', [
       'inputOptions' => ['autofocus' => 'autofocus', 'class' => 'form-control transparent']
 ])->textInput()->input('montant', ['placeholder' => "المبلغ "])->label(false); ?>
            </div><!--End Form-group-->
        </div><!-- col -->

         <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                 <?php echo $form->field($model, 'date', [
       'inputOptions' => ['autofocus' => 'autofocus', 'class' => 'form-control transparent']
 ])->textInput()->input('date', ['placeholder' => "تاريخ التذكير "])->label(false); ?>
            </div><!--End Form-group-->
        </div><!-- col -->

        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                 <?php echo $form->field($model, 'phone', [
       'inputOptions' => ['autofocus' => 'autofocus', 'class' => 'form-control transparent']
 ])->textInput()->input('phone', ['placeholder' => "رقم الجوال"])->label(false); ?>
            </div><!--End Form-group-->
        </div><!-- col -->



        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">

                    <?php echo $form->field($model, 'remarks', [
       'inputOptions' => ['autofocus' => 'autofocus', 'class' => 'form-control transparent']
 ])->textInput(['rows' =>6])->input('remarks', ['placeholder' => "ملاحظات"])->label(false); ?>
            </div><!-- form-group -->
        </div><!-- col -->
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group" style="text-align:center "> 


    <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'إرسال ' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>



            </div><!-- form-group -->
        </div><!-- col -->
         <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
    </form><!--End-->
</div><!-- container -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you forget to specify `method` attribute of your HTML form?

```
<form method="POST" ...>
```

Looks like form just being submitted as GET request

Comment: did you means in my active Form  <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin() ?>

Comment: Ah, ok that should be POST by default

Comment: I forgot to tell you that I added this function in my site controller            public function beforeAction($action) {
        $this->enableCsrfValidation = false;
        return parent::beforeAction($action);
    }

Comment: Code seems ok. Maybe redirect is cached. Try to repeat with cache disabled. For example, use Chrome Developer Console with `Disable cache` checkbox on `Network` tab.

Comment: I deleted the create action on my verb behavior, but the same error

Comment: That's not related to a problem. `VerbFilter` does different thing. It **checks** which method was used to request an action.

Comment: I do not understand what you're saying with "Try to repeat with cache disabled. For example, use Chrome Developer Console with Disable cache checkbox on Network tab"

Comment: I meant that browser could possibly cache response with redirect and now you maybe receive cached redirect.

Comment: i solved it :D i add this above the   "<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>" ================> <div class="subsidize-form ">

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my english before. Can you edit your post and add your complete `ActiveForm::begin()` code. for alternate fix, you can try to remove the create action on your verb behavior like this :

```
'verbs' => [
        'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
        'actions' => [
            'index' => ['get'],
            'view' => ['get'], 
            'update' => ['get', 'put', 'post'],
            'delete' => ['post', 'delete'],
        ],
    ],
```